# Why does numpy.astype throw a memory error when the nparray size is below the memory limit?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
N = 12500
x = np.random.randint(100, size=(N,N)) # int32
x = x.astype('int16', copy=False)
```

throws

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (12500, 12500) and data type int16

For some reason `np.random.randint(100, size=(N,N),dtype='int16')` works. The problem is that I have to load an npz compressed file (which I represent as a random nparray here) and then convert from int32 to int16.

I used memory_profiler to check it out, running `python -m memory_profiler ./testProc.py`

```
import numpy as np
@profile
def test_size(N=12500):
    x = np.random.randint(100, size=(N,N))
    x = x.astype('int16', copy=False)
    del(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_size()
```

yielding

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     2   24.648 MiB   24.648 MiB   @profile
     3                             def test_size(N=2500*5):
     4  620.781 MiB  596.133 MiB       x = np.random.randint(100, size=(N,N))
     5  620.789 MiB    0.008 MiB       print(x.shape)
     6  620.789 MiB    0.000 MiB       print(x.dtype)
     7  620.793 MiB    0.004 MiB       x = x.astype('int16', copy=False)
     8                                 del(x)
```

with the same error as before (hence the conversion in line 7 fails).

As far as I can tell, I should not have a memory problem. The array (12500 by 12500) is roughly 600 MB as int32 and 300 MB as int16. So I am not even close to the ~2 GB limit of Python 32 bit on Windows 10. Unless there is some internal conversion to float64/int64 before converting to int16? Or something along that line. I have 32 GB ram installed, so that should not be the culprit.

I am aware that I can slice the data and/or switch to Python 64 bit - but what's up with this memory problem when I am far from the memory limit (at least as far as I can tell)?

Found this: [How to fix "numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError" while performing MNIST digit classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748040/how-to-fix-numpy-core-exceptions-memoryerror-while-performing-mnist-digit-cla) , where it seems like switching to Linux solves the problem (not an option for me). Is it a Windows problem? Something along the lines of contiguous memory allocation?

Also found this [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type). Could it be some overcommit handling problem in Windows?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `astype` will create a copy when converting between these dtypes.

Comment: also with copy='false'? Besides, even with a copy it should only be maximally 1.3 GB - still not close to the 2 GB limit.

Comment: DId you read the `astype` docs, with a focus on the `copy` parameter?  My guess is that the cumulative space taken up by your arrays puts the last action over the limit.  But reasoning about the exact bounds of memory limits is tricky, and I don't like to intentional test it.

Comment: Yes: "By default, astype always returns a newly allocated array. If this is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy." Still don't understand why it would give a memory error even if copy='True'. Perhaps astype recasts the array internally as int/float64? Or creates more copies...

Comment: To change from int32 to int16 is has to make a copy.  It will be smaller, but it will still be a new array with new data buffer.  It can't be a `view`.  But I can't replicate your situation.  What happens if you do `y = x.copy()` instead of the `astype`?

Comment: So, I can't reproduce it on my work laptop - works fine... Does not work on my home and work desktop - unfortunately I am away on a business trip at the moment and can't check the python/numpy versions on my desktops. I am running python 2.7.4 and numpy 1.17.2 on my laptop. Will check what versions my desktops are running when I get back in a weeks time.

Comment: Well, it works now for N=12500. But for say N=14000 it still gives the error. (should be around 770 MB. Which when doing x.copy() should still be less than 1.6 GB). Is it just Windows that's toying with me?